# Regex - Filter for atypical filetypes

Tags: regex, filenames

I have a folder filled with plain text files with filenames formatted as follows:

```
00001.7c53336b37003a9286aba55d2945844c
00002.9c4069e25e1ef370c078db7ee85ff9ac
00003.860e3c3cee1b42ead714c5c874fe25f7
00002.d94f1b97e48ed3b553b3508d116e6a09
00001.7848dde101aa985090474a91ec93fcf0
```

**After I acquire the filenames as strings, how can I filter them so that all relevant files are accepted and everything else is rejected?**

- I could reformat all files in a controlled environment to strip the
  string up to the the `.`, then add another `.` and a constant
  filetype.
- I could try to set a fixed acceptable value for the length of the
  string after the `.`.
- I could exclude some specific filetypes and hope nothing else slips
  through.

All this methods require me to rename the files or make sure in first person that there is nothing else in the folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The files all have a very long extension. You could use the following to select files which have exactly 32 character extension.

```
\.[^.]{32}$
```

Or something like

```
\.[^.]{8,}$
```

Which matches files whose extension is at least 8 characters.

A close look reveals that (at least) in your example the only alphabetic characters are `a, b, ..., f` so you could restrict your search more with:

```
\.[0-9a-f]{8,}$
```

Also in all the example the file name has exactly 5 digits and start with (at least) double `0` which we could incorporate with:

```
^0{2}\d{3}\.[0-9a-f]{8,}$
```

Comment: I considered this options and it seems the best so far, but I wonder if there is a more strict condition.

Comment: Seems possible (see updated answer) but I also wonder how typical your examples are.

Comment: They are several thousand files, all formatted in the same way. The be fair I can probably get by without a rigorous filtering, but I'm curious to know if the option is there.

Comment: Thanks. But I can think of a small improvement which would *require* the extension to contain numbers -- but can't remember how to do that in regex.

Comment: Maybe something like this? [^\s]+.[^\s]+[0-9]+[^\s]+